# SignalR doesn't reach JS client function

Tags: javascript, c#, signalr

I can successfully call testFunc() on my server. But the Invoke simply never gets to my testFuncCallback() function. Since I can call the server, the connection appears to be fine.
Any idea what's going on?

BACKEND:

```
[HubName("testHub")]
public class testHub: Hub
{
    public void testFunc()
    {
        Clients.Caller.Invoke("testFuncCallback");
    }
}
```

JS:

```
$scope.lTestHub = $scope.$parent.signalrConnection.testHub;
$scope.lTestHub.on('testFuncCallback', function () {
    alert("jo");
});
$scope.lTestHub.server.testFunc();
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the line

```
$scope.lTestHub.on('testFuncCallback', function () {
```

to

```
$scope.lTestHub.client('testFuncCallback', function () {
```

That should do it.

See simple example here:
http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr